# Unity updating licence takes a long time and doesn't start?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I got Unity 5.3.0 from the [Unity official website](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download?ref=personal) ,I installed it,
while running it ,I Signed-in using my Username but it gets stuck in the "Updating License" Window

[image]

can anyone help me with that ?!
thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure you have a stable internet connection, if the problem still occurs try reinstalling the application

Comment: i have a stable connection , i tried reinstall it but same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened for me twice for now. As Sean Powell was saying, you should close and reopen the application few minutes later. I think it's a problem with the license server connection.

Comment: can i make the step of the license on the website ? because i think my firewall prevent the app to connect to the license serve

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling? or restarting the application?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. Don't waste your time with unistall-reinstall. Close Unity, delete Unity_v(your unity version).ulf file in "C:/ProgramData/Unity", and reopen Unity. This should solve your problem.

Comment: i don't have a file called Unity_v(unity version).ulf in my unity setup path C:/ProgramData/Unity
@cenkisabi

Comment: @Gemi not in unity setup path. Check that it isn't "ProgramFiles", it is "ProgramData" and it is a hidden folder.

Comment: i found the path C:/ProgramData/Unity but it is empty folder , i tried to show hidden files but nothing found .what i have to do now  ?! , thanks for your time my bro

Comment: it's so weird. How can it try to update license without any license file in this path. it should create a new one. Sorry but I don't know what is next